# Can Azure AD B2C sign-up & sign-in redirect to own URL, not to URL served by Microsoft?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

Can I use custom URL for Azure AD B2C signup & signin page for web and native appilcation? I dont't want it to redirect to URL served by Azure AD B2C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not available currently. This feature is still on the roadmap.

See details here: Azure AD B2C: [Frequently asked questions (FAQ)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs#can-i-use-my-own-urls-on-my-sign-up-and-sign-in-pages-that-are-served-by-azure-ad-b2c-for-instance-can-i-change-the-url-from-contosob2clogincom-to-logincontosocom).

Comment: How if, can we programmatically sign up/sign in user from app to azure ad within the application ?